# non-generic type error in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I just updated MVC4 WebAPI from beta to RC, and now this part of the code doesn't work.
I read from here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e90d582a-7023-44a1-b311-4fe1370b0314/ that I have to use

`Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response)`

However there's no implementation of `CreateResponse` which takes two parameters? So I wonder how I should go on with to fix this part?

```
public HttpResponseMessage<Response> Login(string username, string password)
{
       ApiResponse<string> user = am.LogOn(username, password);
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(username + " - " + password);
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User status is: " + user.Status);

       switch (user.Status)
       {   
           case ResponseStatus.OK:
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.Value);
              return new HttpResponseMessage<Response>(new Response { Token = user.Value, ValidTo = user.ValidTo });
           default:
              return new HttpResponseMessage<Response>(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> However there's no implementation of CreateResponse which takes two parameters?

Sure, [there is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Login(string username, string password)
{
    ApiResponse<string> user = am.LogOn(username, password);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(username + " - " + password);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User status is: " + user.Status);

    switch (user.Status)
    {   
        case ResponseStatus.OK:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.Value);
            return Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                new Response { Token = user.Value, ValidTo = user.ValidTo }
            );
         default:
             return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that one already but VS2010 says there's no such overload method :/

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me in the RTM. It also worked in the RC.

Comment: However I still don't get that as an option. When I updated to RC I used this package. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client is it correct, or do I lack some other package?

Comment: That's the client side HttpClient. It has nothing to do with the server side package.

Comment: ok it turned out I needed to install this package as well http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/4.0.20710.0